# Игнорировать файл локально, но оставить его в репозитории

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

Есть файл, который я хочу залить в репозиторий и больше его там не изменять, но локально он изменятся будет. Как это можно реализовать? Как сделать так, чтобы Visual Studio Code не предлагал добавить его в коммит, а игнорировал его?

Comment: Залить файл, добавить его в .gitignore. По идее всё

Comment: Никак. Файл либо под контролем git, либо нет. Третьего не дано. Меняйте концепцию, например в гит можно положить файл file.example или file.default

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так не работает

Comment: Попробуйте 3 пунктом ещё удалить файл из индекса так: `git rm --cached [file]`, где вместо `[file]` надо указать путь до файла.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git update-index --skip-worktree <file_name>`

Локальные изменения будут игнорироваться git'ом при коммите. Но при merge/pull изменения будут подтягиваться, и могут быть конфликты.

Отключается командой `git update-index --no-skip-worktree <file_name>`

PS Этот флаг сбрасывается, а содержимое файла откатывается при выполнении `git reset --hard`